# Given a set of numbers, determine if a given number can be calculated

Tags: algorithms

Similar Question: [Algorithm to find if a number is sum of multiples of other numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022960/algorithm-to-find-if-a-number-is-sum-of-multiples-of-other-numbers)

If this isn't the right place to ask, please let me know and I'll migrate the question.

From time to time, my friends and I play a game with cards(the usual 52 card deck).  We draw 4 random cards, and try to use the 4 numbers in any order, using the usual arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /) and try to make 24 out of it(face cards are regarded as 10).

Is there an algorithm to see if 4 numbers are capable of calculating to 24? I've seen a very brute force algorithm that recursively goes through all possible combinations of numbers and operations, but I am hoping for a more efficient method. More generally, can m numbers between 1 and 10 result in a number n through arithmetic operations?